# PHP strtotime epoch timestamp possible bug

Tags: php

From my knowledge UNIX epoch starts at 01-01-1970 00:00.

So why

`echo strtotime('01-01-1970 00:00');` returns `-3600` ?

I'm using PHP Version 5.6.15 and CodeIgniter 3.0.4. I've also tried using/without

`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IND');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the timezone set, see if it is the cause:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

If it is other than `UTC`, set it to `UTC`

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I don't know why the default timezone was set to Europe/Berlin. I'm living in Indonesia, and my windows workstation's timezone is set to Bangkok,Hanoi,Jakarta.

Comment: Probably because of the timezone set in your `php.ini` or maybe there's a config file in CodeIgniter that set your timezone to Europe/Berlin. Nevertheless, if you will be using CodeIgniter, set your desired timezone in its `config.php`.

Comment: Changing codeigniter's `config.php` doesn't do anything, but changing `php.ini` timezone works.